How can I fix black lines on the rear LCD screen?

How could I fix the two black vertical lines on my rear LCD screen?

Can you clarify where is this black line?

@RomeoNinov I'm assuming the two black vertical lines about 1/3 of the way across the screen.

@PhilipKendall, I see, thank you.

What's up with the vignetting? Is that peculiar to your shooting setup or a problem you see with your eyes?

If the lines you talk about are two thin lines in the left part of the screen they are defect of LCD screen.
And if you do not have experience of repair of digital cameras you can do nothing. IMHO they will not appear on the photos so just continue making photos.

Replace the screen. If you don't have the technical expertise to swap out a screen, find someone who does. If they want more than the camera is worth, get another camera instead.
